# Calculate mean of lists in a DataFrame ignoring empty ones

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
               A                    
    1  [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]    
    2  0
    3  [595.0]
    4  0
    5  [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]
    6  0 
    7  0
```

I would like to find the mean for each list ignoring the zeros. I want to get something like:

```
               A                     Mean
1  [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]     38.6
2  0                                    0
3  [595.0]                          595.0
4  0                                    0
5  [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]            470.7
6  0                                    0 
7  0                                    0
```

I tried many possible solutions listed here and none of them worked. This is what I tried so far:

```
df['Mean'] = df.A.apply(lambda x: mean(x))
```

which gives me this error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Also this

```
df['Mean'] = df['A'].mean(axis=1)
```

> ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type

Tried these as well with no luck:

```
a = np.array( df['A'].tolist())
a.mean(axis=1)

mean(d for d in a if d)
```

Is there something else I can try that would give me the expected outcome? Thanks for your help.

Comment: what is the `dtype()` of `A` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
import numpy as np

def calculate_mean(x):
    if isinstance(x["A"], Iterable):
        x["mean"] = np.mean(x["A"])
    else:
        x["mean"] = x["A"]
    return x

df = df.apply(lambda x: calculate_mean(x), axis=1)
```

Edit -

```
df["mean"] = df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x["A"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Actually `np.mean` handles both iterables and `ints`, so no need for checking if each row is an iterable. `df.A.map(np.mean)` works

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a list comprehension and compute the [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) where a given row is a list, which can be checked with [`isinstance`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html). This is necessary or otherwise you will be getting:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

As the function is expecting an iterable. So you can do:

```
from statistics import mean
df['mean'] = [mean(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in df.A]

              A                      mean
0  [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]   38.600000
1                              0    0.000000
2                        [595.0]  595.000000
3                              0    0.000000
4          [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]  470.666667
5                              0    0.000000
6                              0    0.000000
```

---

Or you can also use [`np.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) which does handle both `ints` and iterables:

```
import numpy as np
df['mean'] = df.A.map(np.mean)

               A                      mean
0  [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]   38.600000
1                              0    0.000000
2                        [595.0]  595.000000
3                              0    0.000000
4          [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]  470.666667
5                              0    0.000000
6                              0    0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

okay this works for me

```
                A                    
1   [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]    
2                               0
3                         [595.0]
4                               0
5           [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]
6                               0 
7                               0
```

using [np.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
data['A'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(eval(x)))
```

**Output**

```
                A                            Mean
1   [67.0, 51.0, 23.0, 49.0, 3.0]       38.600000
2                               0       0.000000
3                         [595.0]       595.000000
4                               0       0.000000
5           [446.0, 564.0, 402.0]       470.666667
6                               0       0.000000
7                               0       0.000000
```